# Cannot find ScriptingBridge.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, scripting-bridge

I am new to objective-C.

I have programmed my first App in the last 2 months.  I am now trying to access **iTunes information** and the coding appears to be straight forward but I cannot locate the `ScriptingBridge.framework`.

I am using Xcode 4.5.  I have tried using the "+" button in the Link Binaries with Libraries section of Build Phases but `ScriptingBridge.framework` does not appear on the list.  I have tried opening the framework directory in Finder with no luck. I cannot find a way to download the file independently from installing Xcode.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
BobT

Answer (score 2):

`ScriptingBridge.framework` is not available for Cocoa Touch.

Comment: That would explain it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the scriptingBridge framework with an iOS Project. You only can use it with a cocoa application project. In a cocoa application project you can add the framework under

> Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> +

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html